# Why does replacing class name using Javascript if statement not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
$(document).ready(checkWidth);
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
function checkWidth() {
var $window = $(window);
$("pre").text($window.width());
if ($window.width() < 321) {
       $('.grve-tablet-column-1-4')
       .removeClass('grve-tablet-column-1-2').addClass('grve-tablet-column-1');      
 }
else {
       $('.grve-tablet-column-1')
       .removeClass('grve-tablet-column-1').addClass('grve-tablet-column-1-2');                
    }
}
```

```html
<footer id="grve-footer">

    <div class="grve-container">
      <div id="grve-footer-area" class="grve-section" data-section-type="fullwidth-background" style="visibility: visible; margin-left: 158px; margin-right: 158px;">
   <div class="grve-row">
<div class="grve-column-1-4 grve-tablet-column-1-2"><div id="text-3" class="grve-widget widget widget_text">   <div class="textwidget"><ul class="footerlist">
<li class="maintitle"><a href="http://www.sine.co/">Home</a></li>
<li class="title"><a href="http://www.sine.co/features/">Features</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.sine.co/venue-setup/">Venue Setup</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.sine.co/visitors-app/">Visitor's App</a></li>
<li class="title"><a href="http://www.sine.co/pricing/">Pricing</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.sine.co/venue-plan-request/">Venue Plan Request</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.sine.co/venue-hardware/ ">Venue Hardware</a></li>
</ul></div>
  </div></div><div class="grve-column-1-4 grve-tablet-column-1-2"><div id="text-2" class="grve-widget widget widget_text">   <div class="textwidget"><ul class="footerlist">
<li class="maintitle"><a href="http://www.sine.co/support/">Support</a></li>
<li><a href="https://sine.freshdesk.com/support/home"> FAQ</a></li>
<li class="secondtitle"><a href="https://admin.sine.co/">Try Sine for Free<br>Enterprise Login</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.sine.co/privacy/">Privacy Policy</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.sine.co/terms-of-use/">Terms of Use</a></li>
</ul></div>
  </div></div><div class="grve-column-1-4 grve-tablet-column-1-2"><div id="text-4" class="grve-widget widget widget_text">   <div class="textwidget"><ul class="footerlist">
<li class="maintitle">Free Download</li>
<li><a href="https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/sine/id784906271?mt=8"><img src="http://www.sine.co/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/appstorebutton.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.sine.sinepass&amp;hl=en"><img src="http://www.sine.co/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/googleplaybutton.png"></a></li>

</ul></div>
  </div></div><div class="grve-column-1-4 grve-tablet-column-1-2"><div id="text-5" class="grve-widget widget widget_text">   <div class="textwidget"><ul class="footerlist">
<li class="mail"><a href="mailto:info@sine.co">info@sine.co</a></li>
<li class="skype"><a href="skype:sinehelp?call">sinehelp</a></li>
<li class="phone"><a href="tel:+61881215956">+61 8 8121 5956</a></li>
<li class="twitter"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/SineHQ">SineHQ</a></li>
<li class="linkedin"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/sinepass">SineHQ</a></li>
</ul></div>
  </div></div>   </div>
  </div>
    

       <div id="grve-footer-bar" class="grve-section" data-section-type="fullwidth-element" data-align-center="yes" style="visibility: visible; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; margin-left: 158px; margin-right: 158px;">

    <div class="grve-row">
     <div class="grve-column-1-2">
      <div class="grve-copyright">
       <p style="text-align: center;">Copyright 2015 Sine Group Pty Ltd. Patents Pending.</p>       <a href="http://www.bugejastudio.com" class="bugeja">Website by Bugeja Studio</a>
      </div>
     </div>
     
    </div>
   </div>


    </div>

   </footer>
```

I would like to find out how i would go replacing class names, using JavaScript for 4 divs in my footer named: class="grve-column-1-4 grve-tablet-column-1-2".

I have tried using this code with no luck:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $window = $(window);

    // Function to handle changes to style classes based on window width
    function checkWidth() {
        if ($window.width() < 321) {
            $('.grve-tablet-column-1-2').removeClass('grve-tablet-column-1-2').addClass('grve-tablet-column-1');
        }
    }

    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();

    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

What happens is when you access the website on mobile, the footer looks like this:

[image: demo]

To fix this issue i can change the classes of these 4 divs to grve-tablet-column-1, and as a result it will organise under a single column like this:

[image: demo]

Comment: I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntuyte5y/)] of your code and it seems to be working

Comment: Can you say which browser your are testing with (version included )

Comment: Google Chrome Developer Tools

Comment: when i add this script using JS console it says undefined is not a function?

Comment: this example is almost a copy of your code, `$("pre").text($window.width());` is probably what is throwing the error, other than that it is your code, with of course some modification with the CSS and the HTML

Comment: i think it could be with pre, im not sure tho because when i removed it i still go a underfined function, i added the html of the footer for your view.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u4cn338g/3/

Comment: There is no CSS, http://jsfiddle.net/u4cn338g/4/ I added some and it seems to be working , your css might have some issue , or some other javascript might be causing the problem

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
// Execute on load
$(document).ready(checkWidth);
// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
// Function to handle changes to style classes based on window width
function checkWidth() {
var $window = $(window);
$("pre").text($window.width());
if ($window.width() < 321) {
       $('.grve-tablet-column-1-2')
       .removeClass('grve-tablet-column-1-2').addClass('grve-tablet-column-1');      
 }
else {
       $('.grve-tablet-column-1')
       .removeClass('grve-tablet-column-1').addClass('grve-tablet-column-1-2');                
    }
}
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/u4cn338g/1/

Comment: I tried adding this, but i still have no change when the window is under 321px.

Comment: This is a WordPress theme i dont know if that makes any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Finally after searching for ages, i found that there was a 30% width placed on those elements which was causing the problem.
When i changed the width to 100% the columns started to work using css. 
So turns out i didnt even need the JavaScript, although its some useful information if i need it next time for something :)
Thanks for you help guys.
Alex